# Warn before sending Outlook message

Tags: outlook, ms-office

My Outlook Address book by default storing e-mail addresses in the combination of upper and lower case letters, in that case below code is not working for me. Please advise.

Comment: So what is your code?

Comment: below code? where is it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

  Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
  Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
  Dim i
  Dim prompt As String


On Error Resume Next
 ' use lower case for the address
 ' LCase converts all addresses in the To field to lower case

  Checklist = "firstname.lastname@domain.com"


 Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
  For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
  Set recip = Recipients.Item(i)

 If InStr(LCase(recip), LCase(Checklist)) Then
      prompt$ = "You sending this to this messgae to Treasurer  " & Item.To & ". Are you sure you want to send it?"
       If MsgBox(prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
         Cancel = True
       End If
  End If

Next i


End Sub
```